# Зачем использовать redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Я новичок в redux. У меня есть react приложение с redux. Есть reducer с такой структурой:

```
const state = {
   array: [];
}
```

Так же у меня есть такие action:

```
export const getArray = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await fetch('какой-то api');
    if(res.ok) {
       dispatch(setArray(await res.json()))
    }
}

export const setArray = (data) => ({
   type: "SET_ARRAY",
   payload: data
})
```

Код в моем компоненте:

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getArray())
}, [])
```

Должен ли я использовать redux-thunk, и если не должен, то почему?

Какой подход будет лучше?

Ведь можно же использовать такой код:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const res = await fetch('какой-то api');
    if(res.ok) {
       dispatch(setArray(await res.json()))
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, redux-thunk, нужен для того, чтобы не дублировать одну логику например запроса на сервер в разных компонентах, при этом еще импортируя действия кладущие данные в store.

Comment: [Ответ на ваш вопрос кроется здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/460206)